# Is libodbc1 preventing me from upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

```
(base) user@computer:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for user: 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

(base) user@computer:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease        
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [51.3 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [57.9 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [294 kB]
Get:12 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [295 kB]
Get:13 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:14 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,272 B]
Fetched 964 kB in 1s (696 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

(base) user@computer:~$ apt list --upgradeable -a
Listing... Done
libodbc1/bionic 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3]
libodbc1/bionic,now 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.3.7]
```

It seems like I can't upgrade because libodbc1 isn't being upgraded?

As well; I can't upgrade with the GUI software updater. The "Upgrade..." button doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks.

*libodbc1 was held back:

```
(base) user@computer:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

**Final edit**

The following command worked for my specific issue:

```
sudo apt-install libodbc1
```

This permitted the upgrade to proceed.

Thank you!

Comment: Then try `sudo apt full-upgrade` ,,, that might solve the problem. Read the output carefully before answering Yes as the command might remove packages if needed.

Comment: Yes! Installing libodbc1 with:

`sudo apt-install libodbc1`

worked!

Please also see another post I will be making since I then borked the upgrade -.-